# How to redirect non-existent website from one domain to an existing website on another domain using https and http?

Tags: redirect, https, dns

I purchased a domain name (we'll call it "exampledomain.com"). There is no website tied to the domain and there are no plans to do so.

I want to redirect all URL variants of this domain to an existing website I also own: (we'll call it "destinationdomain.com")

If a user types any of the following, I want to redirect them to https://www.destinationdomain.com/

1. https://exampledomain.com/
2. https://www.exampledomain.com/
3. http://exampledomain.com/
4. http://www.exampledomain.com/

How would I set this up?

What I believe I need to do is:

1. Add exampledomain.com as a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) to an existing SANs supported SSL I own for an existing website.
2. Point IPs of exampledomain.com to the IP used by destinationdomain.com
3. Add code to destinationdomain.com so that when it receives requests from the above exampledomain.com variants, it performs a 301 redirect to https://www.destimationdomain.com

POSSIBLE ALTERNATIVE?

1. Set up domain forwarding from exampledomain.com to https://www.destinationdomain.com/
2. Add exampledomain to destinationdomain.com's Subject Alternative Names (SANs)?

Is this accurate, or can I achieve this without step 3?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Point IPs of exampledomain.com to the IP used by destinationdomain.com

You need to point it *somewhere*. It doesn't have to be the same server as you are using for your other site. (e.g. I might do this all in AWS and use an S3 bucket to do the redirect).

> Add code to destinationdomain.com so that when it receives requests from the above exampledomain.com variants, it performs a 301 redirect to https://www.destimationdomain.com

The server that you point the new domain to does need to issue a 301 redirect.

This doesn't need to be anything to do with the old domain though. Even if they are hosted on the same server, you can use Virtual Name Hosting to use separate server configurations.

> Add exampledomain.com as a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) to an existing SANs supported SSL I own for an existing website.

You will need the domain in the certificate for whatever server is hosting it. If you're using the same server then setting it up as a SAN makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin!  Just to clarify, exampledomain.com doesn't have a website tied to it.  It's just the domain name.  Does that change the above?

Comment: This answer assumes that. You *need* to point it to an HTTP server so the HTTP server can issue the 301 redirect.